# spring DIC read properties file inside maven structure

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, filenotfoundexception

I've got a spring XML file containing beans creating data source for hibernate:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>properties/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

This is how this file looked like before using Maven. Now I've placed this file in src/main/resources/properties/database.properties and I'm getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException` - properties file cannot be found. I changed `<value>properties/database.properties</value>` to `<value>/properties/database.properties</value>` and it still doesn't work. The properties file resides in `/target/classes/properties/database.properties`, so I guess it should be readable from properties/database.properties, since src/main/resources is included in the classpath. What should I correct in the config XML?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add `classpath:` to the property value, as shown below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:properties/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```